# Print VBA Userform as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, userform

I created a long userform that contains alot of information and I had like the user to have option to print if ones he clicks the "print_button".

I have found the following code:

```
private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\Users\" & 
    Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"
    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"
    DoEvents
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 
    Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Path & Me.Name & ".pdf"
    UserForm1.Hide
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code works great and copies the userform as picture to another excel that can be printed

However, It snaps only the shown part of the userform, and since my userform contains scrollbar, it does not print all the information that is in the remaining of the userform.

Is there some option to make it possible to print/snap the whole userform and long page when it contains scrollbar?

thank you

Comment: before printing : form1.height = form1.scrollheight

Comment: Hey, I added it before specialprint and it didnt work. Is there a chance its not working because the height is more than the height of the screen?